# How to take data from a <form> and display the input values in a separate <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 `<div>`

```
<div id="form">
    <form id="myform">
         <input type="text" id="value1"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="display">
    <!--- value1 to be displayed here -->
</div>
```

I need to do this all in 1 file (no `php` or `jsp`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by setting `event listener` on `input field` and writing value of that field inside `div`
Check **example snippet** below

```js
$('#value1').on('input', function() {
  $('#display').text($(this).val());


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="value1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="display">
  <!--- value1 to be displayed here -->
</div>
```

Comment: if I had 12 "text" inputs - would you do the same thing but put some <br/> between each?

Comment: I would make different `<p>` inside this  `div` for each input, so it would be easier  to collect/style text